# Packaging an object for a model with a dynamic route is undefined — why?

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-router

Playing around with with EmberJS, and I'm trying to understand some behaviour with routes right now.

I'm building a test app with the intention of hooking into the Rdio API and displaying albums/songs for various artists.

[Here's a JsBin.](http://jsbin.com/puqokupura/1/)

Right now, there are only two views: The **Index** (a listing of all available albums), and an individual **Album** view.

The dynamic route is defined like so:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("album", { path: "/album/:key" });
});
```

And given a fixture that looks like this...

```
App.ALBUMS = {
 "status": "ok", 
 "result": [
  {
   "key": "a5337866", 
   "icon": "http://rdio3img-a.akamaihd.net/album/a/0/3/000000000051730a/3/square-200.jpg", 
   "artist": "The Decemberists", 
  }, 
  {
   "key": "a5229271", 
   "icon": "http://rdio1img-a.akamaihd.net/album/7/d/a/00000000004fcad7/1/square-200.jpg", 
   "artist": "Nicki Minaj", 
  }, 
  ]
};
```

...the index works just fine:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {albums:App.ALBUMS.result }
  }
});
```

(I've intentionally packaged *App.ALBUMS.result* in an object so that I can pack more information into it later.)

[image: Lyrically Index Page]

However, when I get to the Album view, I get a problem:

```
App.AlbumRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    console.log(params);
    console.log(App.ALBUMS.result.findBy('key',params.key)); //Logs object just fine
    return App.ALBUMS.result.findBy('key',params.key); //ERROR
  }
});
```

Packaging that return value (which should already be an object) in a second object or array though, and it works.

```
// THIS WORKS!: 
return [App.ALBUMS.result.findBy('key',params.key)]; 
// THIS AlSO WORKS!:
return {album: App.ALBUMS.result.findBy('key',params.key)};
```

**Why?**

**App.ALBUMS.result.findBy('key',params.key)** alone should be (and is) returning an object, so why does Ember choke on it?

The error itself is rather unhelpful:

```
     Error while processing route: album undefined is not a function TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at EmberObject.extend._setupArrangedContent (http://local.lyrically.com/js/libs/ember-1.9.1.js:34181:27)
    at null._arrangedContentDidChange (http://local.lyrically.com/js/libs/ember-1.9.1.js:34167:14)
    at applyStr (http://local.lyrically.com/js/libs/ember-1.9.1.js:19677:29)
    at sendEvent (http://local.lyrically.com/js/libs/ember-1.9.1.js:14115:13)
    at notifyObservers (http://local.lyrically.com/js/libs/ember-1.9.1.js:17488:9)
    at propertyDidChange (http://local.lyrically.com/js/libs/ember-1.9.1.js:17291:7)
    at iterDeps (http://local.lyrically.com/js/libs/ember-1.9.1.js:17373:11)
    at dependentKeysDidChange (http://local.lyrically.com/js/libs/ember-1.9.1.js:17329:9)
    at propertyDidChange (http://local.lyrically.com/js/libs/ember-1.9.1.js:17287:9)
    at iterDeps (http://local.lyrically.com/js/libs/ember-1.9.1.js:17373:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ember (apparently) likes it when model is an Ember object. The good news is that it's very easy to convert a regular object to an instance of Ember object - you just do `Ember.create(yourRegularObject)`

Therefore, returning the following

`return Ember.Object.create(Lyrically.ALBUMS.result.findBy('key',params.key));`

fixes your issue.

Working demo [here](http://jsbin.com/yulinu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)